# expected ";" before "{" token error in function switch in c

Tags: c, compiler-errors, switch-statement

I am learning the C language as my very first language. I am using the gcc code blocks compiler. I was trying to use the `switch-case` statements after watching a video. I am getting an error that the `;` was expected before `{` statement token. I tried but could not find any mistake. Can anyone please help me out with this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int b,sum,avg,multi,choise,s[5],a[3];
    printf("Please select any option\n");
    printf("1. I want addition of numbers.\n");
    printf("2. I want to take average of numbers.\n");
    printf(" 3. I want the multiplication table of a number.\n");
    printf("4. Exit\n");

    Switch(choise)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("You have selected the 1st option,\n");
            printf("Please enter any 5 numbers you want to add.\n");
            gets(s);
            sum=s[0]+s[1]+s[2]+s[3]+s[4];
            printf("The sum of the numbers you entered is %d",sum);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("You have selected the 2nd option,\n");
            printf("Enter any 3 numbers to take average of them.\n");
            gets(a);
            avg=a[0]+a[1]+a[2]/3;
            printf("The average of the three numbers you entered is %d",avg);
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("You have selected the 3rd option,\n");
            printf("Please enter the number you want the  multiplication table of,\n");
            scanf("%d",&multi);
            for(b=1;b<=10;b++)
            {
            printf("%d * %d = %d\n",multi,b,multi*b);
            }
            break;
        default:
            printf("invalid input.\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Switch(choise)` -->> `switch(choise)`

Comment: One of the points of creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), besides getting the minimal program that exhibits your problem, is as a way to find errors like these yourself.

Comment: `gets(s);` --> `scanf("%d %d %d %d %d", s, s + 1, s + 2, s + 3, s + 4);`

Comment: `avg=a[0]+a[1]+a[2]/3;` --> `avg=(a[0]+a[1]+a[2])/3;`

Comment: @Tan_007  You forgot to enter a value into the variable choise.:)

Comment: Beginning was hard. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyword is `switch`, not `Switch`. You confused your compiler into thinking you are calling a function, and as such missing a statement terminator after the line, like so:

```
Switch(choice);
```

Comment: oh god...thank you sir..solved the mistake...was trying since last two hours..thank you..